# joomla exceptions are not being logged

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I have a joomla site, running 3.0.2* and I have noticed that exceptions caught by joomla are not being logged anywhere. I am currently using the built-in database logging, initialized by the following code, placed within the onAfterInitialise function of a custom plugin.

```
        // Initialize logging. 
    jimport('joomla.log.log');
    $config = jFactory::getConfig();

    JLog::addLogger(array(
        'logger'    => 'database',
        'db_driver' => $config->get('dbtype'),
        'db_host'   => $config->get('host'),
        'db_user'   => $config->get('user'),
        'db_pass'   => $config->get('password'),
        'db_prefix' => $config->get('dbprefix'),            
        'db_database' => ctaSettings::get('logging.db'),
        JLog::ALL,
        ''
    ));
```

ctaSettings::get is a class method that retrieves the name of the database used for logging. I can verify that it works correctly and that commands such as the following are being logged:

```
JLog::add(__LINE__. " - ". __FILE__, JLog::INFO, 'cat');
```

But, if an exception is thrown in a component, nothing is being logged. Should Joomla be logging caught exceptions? And is there a way to get Joomla's built-in error handling to automatically log these things? We have quite a bit of custom code, and it would be inconvenient if every custom component, plugin, and module had to be modified to explicitly log errors as they were thrown.

`* We're working on upgrading, but cannot at the moment.`

Comment: Did you check Joomla log files? Maybe, Joomla wright all exceptions there (becase it should).

Comment: I have checked the log files, and didn't see the exception in any of those entries. Since I first installed Joomla, the logs have been quirky. When you say "it should". Do you mean "it would make sense for it to do so", or do you know that Joomla's error handler also logs exceptions caught?

Comment: No, Joomla do not loggins exceptions because it's not necessary. You better look for solution here (make system plugin I guess): http://docs.joomla.org/Using_JLog

Comment: I will say that once you upgrade you'll see a number of improvements to logging.

Comment: Ok. So, maybe I'm supposed to use php's set_exception_handler function to set the error handler? The only issue there is that joomla still seems to be trapping any exception that takes place in a component, and not passing the exception to the php handler. This applies, even if you set JError::$legacy to false.

Answer (score 0):

I used the setErrorHandling method to enable exception logging. It is deprecated, but my understanding is that no alternative has yet been introduced. So, I'm going to keep this open, in case someone has a better answer, but the following line of code fixed my problem.

```
JError::setErrorHandling(JLog::ALL & ~JLog::WARNING, 'log');
```

The & ~JLog::WARNING is to specify not to log the "such and such is deprecated" errors. It's not ideal, but it seems like the only answer that works.

Comment: `JError` is deprecated